# Is this function from $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ to $\mathbb{R}_+×S^n$ surjective?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\phi :\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}→\mathbb{R}_+×S^n$ bedefined as $$\phi(x)=\phi(x_1,\cdots,x_{n+1})=\left(\|x\|,\frac{x_1}{\|x\|},\cdots,\frac{x_{n+1}}{\|x\|}\right).$$

I have to prove that $\phi$ is continuous, surjective and injective.

For the injective part I assumed that if $x\neq x'$ then $x_{i}\neq x'_{i}$ for at least some $i$, then if $\|x\|\neq \|x'\|$ we are done, however if $\|x\|= \|x'\|$ then $\dfrac{x_i}{\|x\|}\neq \dfrac{x'_i}{\|x\|}$ for at least some $i$. Is this correct?

For the surjective part I do not know what to do.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you write down an inverse function to $\phi$?

Comment: maybe $\psi(||x||,\dfrac{x_1}{||x||},...,\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{||x||})=(\dfrac{||x||x_1}{||x||},...,\dfrac{||x||x_{n+1}}{||x||})$??

Comment: or maybe, for each $y=(a,y_1,...,y_{n+1}), a>0, (y_1)^2+...+(y_{n+1})^2=1$ there exists $x=(ay_1,...,ay_{n+1})$ such that $\phi (x)=y$??? where $||x||=a$

Comment: If you are still interested after a year: $\psi(t,y) = t \cdot y$.

Comment: haha I think it was posted 2 weeks ago. Thank you very much

Comment: I should read more carefully ;-) But check $\psi \circ \phi = id$ and $\phi \circ \psi =id$.

Answer (score 1):

Here $\phi (x)=(|x|,\frac{x}{|x|})$. If $ \phi (x)=\phi (y)$, then
$|x|=|y|,\ \frac{x}{|x|}=\frac{y}{|y|}$ so that $x=y$. injective

If $x\in S^n$, then $\phi(x)=(1,x)$ and $\phi(lx)=(l,x)$ for $l>0$
Hence surjective.

If $|x-y|<\delta$, then assume that $|x|>|y|$

Note that $$ |x-y|\geq ||x|-|y||,\ |\frac{x}{|x|}|y|-y|$$ so that
\begin{align*}|\phi(x)-\phi (y)| &=|(|x|,\frac{x}{|x|}) - (
|y|,\frac{y}{|y|} )|\\&\leq (|x|,0)-(|y|,0)| +|(0,\frac{x}{|x|}) - (
0,\frac{y}{|y|} )|\\& \leq ||x|-|y|| + | \frac{x}{|x|} |y| -y| |y|
\\&\leq \delta +\delta |y| \end{align*}

Hence it is continuous